# Custom django template tag/argument ignoring condition

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have an `Event` class. Events have `presenters`. The `presenters` are placed into an 'Attendee' list. Presenters are supposed to have a flag of sorts displaying that they are infact a presenter in a list of attendees. Ie: a checkmark beside their avatar `{% if is_presenter %}`. As of right now it's adding a checkmark to all attendees.

I just want the flag to show for `presenters` only. What am I doing wrong? How do I just add get the checkmark to just show for those presenting?. (Also, I don't know if my title was correct for this situation. Let me know).

Models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    presenters = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profile = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Views:

```
def event(request, id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=id)
    is_attending = False
    is_presenter = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        attendees = [a.profile for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]
        if profile in attendees:
            is_attending = True        
    for presenter in event.presenters.all():
        is_attending = True
        try:
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='profiles', model='profile')
            Attendee.objects.get(event=event, content_type=content_type, object_id=presenter.id)
            is_presenter = True
        except Attendee.DoesNotExist:
            Attendee(event=event, profile=presenter).save()
```

Template:

```
{% for attendee in event.attendees %}
     <div class="inline-block">   
        <a href="/profile/{{ attendee.profile.get_type|lower}}/{{ attendee.profile.user.username }}"{% if attendee.profile.is_presenter %}title="Presenter" class="tooltip-below"{% endif %}>
        <img width=30 height=30 src="{% if attendee.profile.avatar %}{% thumbnail attendee.profile.avatar 30x30 crop %}{% else %}{{ DEFAULT_AVATAR }}{% endif %}" />
        </a>
        {% if is_presenter %}
            <i class="icon-ok-sign"></i>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't right understand your question. But it seems that the problem is that your `is_presenter` flag is not a property of your object. Because python allow to create properties dinamically, perhaps, the solution may be to set this boolean var to the model in this way:

```
    ...
    if profile in attendees:
        profile.is_attending = True  
for presenter in event.presenters.all():
    presenter.is_attending = True
```

In template:

```
    {% if profile.is_presenter %}
```

*** The elegant solution is to extend Profile model with `is_presenter()` method.***

Comment: Adding your solution makes the checkmarks disappear. It seems the only way for the checkmarks to show at all, is to have `is_presenter` within the `try`. I guess what I'm trying to do is check if the attendees are presenters. If so, show the flag(checkmark). hopefully that clarifies things for you, and thanks for your suggestion.